# How to randomly fill vector<vector<bool>> with 0s and 1s

Tags: c++

What is the easiest way to randomize a `vector<vector<bool>>` with 0s and 1s?  I haven't been able to find an answer online, so a reference if applicable would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3UYHry)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define let const auto&

int main()
{
    let size = 128;
    let inner_size_max = 16;
    vector<vector<bool>> vs(size);

    for(auto &v : vs)
        generate_n(back_inserter(v),rand()%inner_size_max,[]
        {
            return rand()%2==0;
        });

    for(let v : vs)
    {
        for(let b : v)
            cout << b;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on aims, sometimes you don't want to `srand` or do `srand(constant)` deliberately.

Comment: I like your print statement... I stole it, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Arrieta, it is [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 1):

[Live Demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3o88lG%242)

I have a slight preference for a reusable function to generate the individual "rows", and then create the full "matrix" on demand. The run-time is nearly identical as other answers (as determined by the "live workspace" (run time about 0.1 seconds)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<algorithm>

// this is a transparent, reusable function
template<size_t N>
std::vector<bool> generate_bits() {
  std::vector<bool> bits;
  bits.reserve(N);
  for(size_t k=0; k<N; k++) {
    bits.push_back(rand() % 2 == 0);
  }
  return stdbits; // rvo, or use std::move
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<bool>> bits;  
  bits.resize(128);  
  std::generate(bits.begin(), bits.end(), generate_bits<16>);

  // stole the cool printing statement
  for(auto&& v : bits) {
    for(auto&& b : v) {
      std::cout<<b;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anybody knows why the run time is so different among compilers? If you try the live workspace demo using an older version of gcc, the run time is cut in half!

Comment: Regarding "// rvo, or use std::move" - you should not use `std::move` here - it would only disable possible `NRVO`. If compiler would fail to use `NRVO` - it would move it in any case automaticly (without `std::move`).